# Delete or change text from .dat file

Tags: c#

I have a program which saves a persons information (Name, Surname, DOB etc.) to a .dat file named Records.dat. Which is the ideal method of deleting one person's information from the file and either replacing it with "DELETED" or just delete the information entirely?

Comment: Why don't you use a database?

Comment: What's the format of the file?  `.dat` could be anything.

Comment: System.IO.File.Delete("records.dat");

Comment: Well I guess that would depend if you care to A) ever UN-delete that person's information and B) want to "remember" that you had deleted it.  If you don't care about those things, then just delete it from the file, otherwise you could indicate it somehow (e.g., if it were XML, you could have a "deleted" flag).

Comment: What good would a bunch of "DELETED" lines in that file do? As itsmatt said, if you don't care about undeleting, remove the whole line and save some space or if you *do* care about undeleting work with flags.

Comment: If you plan to undelete and are trying own database implementation (for whatever reason), then it is worth to have field "deleted" (Name,Surname,DOB,Deleted,etc), set it to true/false, or 1/0 when you need to mark record as deleted.

Comment: @Corack: But removing a record completely would involve a lot of data manipulation (depending on the file format, which isn't specified). Just writing "DELETED" in that record position is pretty inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm unsure why you're not leveraging a database (and it really doesn't matter so it's not a big deal) I'm going to recommend a **logical** delete (i.e. don't really delete it). In the case of a flat file I would recommend prefacing the line with `DELETED|` because that's really easy to parse out when reading rows to list and or searching. So, if you had the line in memory it might look something like this:

```
var line // you've already assigned this
line = string.Format("DELETED|{0}", line);
```

and then you'll need to write that `line` back to the file. I'm not sure how you're writing to the file, but let's assume you know the position of that record in the file for this example:

```
int startIndex // you have already assigned this somewhere
               // it's the starting index of this line

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("path to file", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        bw.Position = startIndex
        bw.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(line), 0, line.Length);
    }
}
```